# Sort List<T> using the property of its property

Tags: c#, sorting, icomparable

I have a model:

```
public class SomeClass {
  public List<Person> Owner {get; set;}
  public int Balance {get;set;}
  . . . .
}
```

and

```
public class Person {
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public Guid PersonID {get;set;}
  . . . .
}
```

I have a wrapper class which handles the sorting:

```
public class SortedResult <ModelType>: Result where ModelType: new() {

  . . . .

  private void SetProperties(IQueryable <ModelType> data, int pageIndex, int pageSize, string orderBy, OrderDirection ? orderDir) {
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(orderBy)) {
      // auto-handles the order-by
      if (orderDir == OrderDirection.Descending) {
        data = data.OrderByDescending(orderBy);
      } else {
        data = data.OrderBy(orderBy);
      }
    }

    int total = data.Count();
    // no ordering
    Data = data.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
    AllData = myIncludeAllData ? data : null;
    PageIndex = pageIndex;
    PageSize = pageSize;
    TotalSize = total;
  }

}
```

As you can see, `SortedResult` allows me to sort any `List<T>` dynamically. Sorting using other properties of `SomeClass` runs ok but when I sort by the `Owner` property, I'm getting error:

> "At least one object must implement IComparable."

I am guessing that it's because the system doesn't know how to sort `List<SomeClass>` by the `Owner` property.

How can I allow `SomeClass` to be sorted by `Owner.Name` if it is sorted using `Owner`? I have seen examples that overrides the `Compare` logic of the model but I don't know where to start.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

@dasblinkenlight's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46811740/sort-listt-using-the-property-of-its-property#comment-80571409) enlightened me. Indeed, it is wrong to sort by `Owner` which is a `List<Person>`.

For the fix, I modified my `SomeClass` model:

```
public class SomeClass {
  public List<Person> Owner {get; set;}
  //should sort using this prop instead of Owner
  public string OwnerName { get 
                             { return string.Join(", ", this.Owner.Select(r => r.Name)); }
                          }
  public int Balance {get;set;}
  . . . .
}
```

Thanks for all the effort everyone.

Comment: `Owner` is a `List<Person>` object, not a `Person` object with a `Name` property.

Comment: correct @dasblinkenlight. Is there something wrong with that?

Comment: There are many `Person` objects in a list, each having its own `Name` If you are sorting `SomeClass` on `Owner`, which of several `Person` objects are you going to pick for `Name` comparison?

Comment: The reason is that `Person` does not implement `IComparable` (but the other properties do) so there is no way to `OrderBy` on the `Person` class.. It should work if you add the syntax to implement the interface to your class: `public class Person : IComparable { public int CompareTo(object obj) { var other = obj as Person; return other == null ? 1 : String.Compare(Name, other.Name, StringComparison.Ordinal); } }`.

Comment: @GeomanYabes Actually implementing IComparable<T>  is more sound advise then IComparable. Just for you to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make some changes to Person class:

```
public class Person : IComparable {
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public Guid PersonID {get;set;}
  // implement the methods for IComparable
}
```

you can find a good sample in this link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: this is the closest I could choose as an answer

Answer (score 0):

`Person` should implement `IComparable<T>` interface. Check the official [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx) for an example.